# Want to access struct pointer's data of type from struct's memory in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct

My program dynamically allocates nodes of type struct pointer. I want to access the data of struct pointer via it's memory address. The main purpose of my question is to test b-tree insert with split. Here is the struct:

```
struct LeafNode
{
    int EmpID[M];
    int Location[M];
    int keys;
};
typedef struct LeafNode* LNodePtr;
```

Here is my test code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int * a = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
    *a = 5; 
    printf("int a created at %p\n", (void *) &a);

    void * addr;

    printf("Give the memory address: ");
    scanf("%p", addr);
    void * addr2 = (void *)addr;
    printf("The value at memory is: %d\n",*(int*)addr2);

return 0;
}
```

Here' s the result:

int a created at 0xbff573b4 
Give the memory address: 0xbff583b4
Segmentation fault

The second step is to cast to LNodePtr instead of int. I don't know if we can use double cast, i.e

```
*(int *(LNodePtr))addr
```

so that i can access

```
struct's EmpID[0]
```

`int` member through memory. Thanks for help.

Comment: When i run the program, the operating system changes the virtual memory address of the process. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void * addr;
```

Allocates a pointer, but does not initialize it.

```
scanf("%p", addr);
```

Reads a pointer into the variable stored at the address held in `addr`. You did not initialize `addr` so this is undefined behaviour.

Perhaps you meant to write:

```
scanf("%p", &addr);
```

But it's very hard to tell. Not least because you talk at length about a `struct` and then have code that does not mention the struct and instead works with `void*`.

---

```
printf("int a created at %p\n", (void *) &a);
```

This prints the address of the variable holding the pointer `a`. If you want to print the value of the pointer, use `a` instead of `&a`.

Comment: I think you mean initializes a pointer, but does not allocate it.

Comment: @Ethan No, I meant what I wrote. That line of code allocates a pointer but does not initialize it. There is a difference between allocating a pointer, a variable which holds an address, and allocating a block of memory whose address may be assigned to a pointer variable.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't dereference a in your printf line, a itself is already a pointer, *a is the int!

```
printf("int a created at %p\n", (void *) a);
```

Also, you should dereference the void* in scanf

```
scanf("%p", &addr);
```

As a general tip, try compiling with the C flag -Wall, so you can easily catch these mistakes.

To answer the question in the comments, in case you have the node address 0x1234, you could do this:

```
MyNode *node = 0x1234;
node->int[0] = 5;
```

Hope that answers the question

Comment: If I use  struct node{int id[5];}MyNode; how can i access id[0] element from the given address instead of *(int*)addr2) cast? Thanks...

Comment: You could go through the array like this:
    MyNode node;
    node.id[0] = 5;
    node.id[1] = 2;
    ...

Comment: I know this access method. We only know the node address and we only want to access id element of struct like for example `code` *(int *(LNodePtr))addr

Comment: I added a bit of text in my response because there's no code support in these comment fields